# IndexError: list index out of range 2 dimension list

Tags: python, list

I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Python27/main.py", line 21, in 
>       matrix[1][1].append(2)
>   IndexError: list index out of range

This is my code

```
file = open("C:\\Python27\\test.txt", "r")

s1 = file.read();
s2 = file.read();

matrix = [[0 for x in range(len(s1))] for x in range(len(s2))]

matrix[1][1].append(2)
print matrix[1][1]
```

`len(s1)` and `len(s2)` is larger than 5

I try using `matrix[1][1] = 2` instead of `matrix[1][1].append(2)`but it won't work.

So what's my mistakes?

Comment: just for the record: You are not asking any question.

Comment: `matrix[1][1].append(2)` will certainly not work as you are trying to append to an `int`

Comment: also you might want to test `len(s2)` again.

Comment: Just a comment on style, I'd use `matrix = [ [0] * len(s1) ] * len(s2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd print len(s1) and len(s2). They are probably not what you expect. And if you want to set row 1 col 1 of matrix you would do:

```
matrix[1][1] = 2
```

because otherwise you are trying to append number 2 to element at (1,1) which is not a list.